# Unable to install new relic on linux using tomcat server

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, newrelic

I have created account on **new relic** and downloaded zip for new relic agent and uploaded to **/etc** directory in my **linux** machine(**tomcat** server).

As per documentations, I follow the following code

```
cd /etc/newrelic
java -jar newrelic.jar install
```

But I am getting following error:

```
Dec 31, 2013 06:14:04 +0000 NewRelic 1 INFO: Agent is using Logback
***** ( ( o))  New Relic Java Agent Installer
***** Installing version 3.2.3 ...
Could not edit start script because:
 .:. Could not locate a Tomcat, Jetty, JBoss, JBoss7 or Glassfish instance in /etc
Try re-running the install command with the -s <AppServerRootDirectory> option or from    <AppServerRootDirectory>/newrelic.
If that doesn't work, locate and edit the start script manually.
No need to create New Relic configuration file because:
 .:. A config file already exists: /etc/newrelic/newrelic.yml
***** Install incomplete
***** Next steps:
For help completing the install, see https://newrelic.com/docs/java/new-relic-for-java
```

Can anyone give me solution for this?

Comment: Sure. First, `export TOMCAT_HOME=""` to where you have tomcat, then `java -jar newrelic.jar install -s $TOMCAT_HOME`.

Comment: I have done this now and getting following error:                                                                                                                             Error parsing arguments
com.newrelic.deps.org.apache.commons.cli.MissingArgumentException: Missing argument for option: s                                                                    Any solution please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the log information provide that it `Could not locate a Tomcat`, you need to provide env var like `TOMCAT_HOME` and so on.
In linux, even if you have installed some software, it can not be conveniently used without adding into `PATH` or some other env var.
In your situation, seems you need to add `TOMCAT_HOME` and `export` it.
Make sure the tomcat is correctly installed!

Comment: this does not answer the question :(

Comment: Even after adding "export TOMCAT_HOME=/usr/share/tomcat", I still got the same result.

Answer (score 1):

I was dealing with the same error, you only need to copy the new-relic.jar file inside the root of your tomcat server and then type:

```
java -jar new-relic.jar install
```

And that's it, it worked for me. Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks! worked like a charm. in my case I had to put newrelic.jar in ..../tomcat/bin

Answer (score 0):

I work in support at New Relic, specializing in the Java agent.

Since Tomcat installations vary between Linux environments, your best bet is to follow the manual installation instructions:

https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/java/java-agent-manual-installation

Scroll down to the Tomcat instructions, which advise you to add the -javaagent flag to your Tomcat startup script. Once you've made that change and started your Tomcat instance, you can verify that the newrelic.jar is included in the startup arguments by issuing a ps -ef | grep java command.

If you need further help, please open a support ticket at support.newrelic.com and we'll be glad to assist.

Comment: This is bad! If you ever update your tomcat installation and replace your catalina.sh newrelic stop working. New Relic should come up with a better solution!! There aren't many distributions that are used and the agent could try to look into at least the most used ones where the actual path of tomcat_home is.

Comment: I´ve tried to do the same thing, but I keep getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Before installing the New Relic the code will fetch the requisite environment parameters like JAVA_HOME, TOMCAT_HOME, etc ( depends on your configuration) and then install the agent on your server. Make sure all the required env variables are defined.

After you have done the above, also check the following:
a) The New Relic should be extraced/installed in your home directory ( in my case /APP)

> > cd /APP
> >
> > Unzip newrelic-java-3.26.1.zip –d /APP

b) The Java agent should be defined in the local properties file ( I have configured it for Hybris server in Dev environment)

> > vim /APP/hybris/config/local.properties
> >
> > Add : -javaagent:/APP/newrelic/newrelic.jar –D newrelic.environment=Development

c) In some cases, it requirs the application specific yml file along with the newrelic.yml file ( in my case hybris.yml)

> > Cd /APP/newrelic
> >
> > mkdir extensions
> >
> > chmod 755 extensions
> >
> > cd /APP/newrelic/extensions
> >
> > vim hybris.yml

[Hybris specific configuration for the hybris.yml file ( use jmx.yml)](https://wiki.hybris.com/display/hybrisALF/New+Relic+Configuration)

Add the jmx.yml data in the hybris.yml after creating the file.

d) Restart your application:
I did it using the following commands:

> > cd /APP/hybris/bin/platform
> >
> > ant clean all

e) You should see the data in sometime. Keep monitoring the new relic logs in:

> > tail -f /APP/newrelic/logs/newrelic_agent.log

Answer (score 0):

Before you do any of these steps, make sure that your *new relic* folder is in inside the folder of your server. That immediately fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The folder newrelic belongs to /usr/share/tomcat/. At least on Ubuntu 16.04 with Tomcat 7. Then also the install command works. Please do not forget to read and adapt the whole newrelic.yml file.